# mysqlclient not building. I am working with Python 3.7

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. Working on a project which required Python 3.7. I installed 3.7 and pointed python3 to 3.7. After that, I tried to install mysqlclient in a virtualenv. It is showing up this error -

```py
 Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /home/shubhank/Documents/venv/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-23peu25b/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-sd651yiu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/shubhank/Documents/venv/include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:
    /usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Dversion_info=(1,4,6,'final',0) -D__version__=1.4.6 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/home/shubhank/Documents/venv/include -I/usr/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    MySQLdb/_mysql.c:38:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
     #include "Python.h"
              ^~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Tried the following as mentioned in the some stackoverflow answers -
`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`
`pip install mysqlclient`
But still this error throws up. At first I thought there was an error with wheel package, so did
`pip install wheel`
But still the issue wasn't solved

Note - Installation of mysqlclient is part of my requirements.txt file

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the header files for the version of python that you are using.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

worked for me on Linux Mint, which is Ubuntu based but I am on python 3.6.